# Live Audio Streaming and Dynamically Generated Channels

Tags: red5, live-streaming, flash-media-server, shoutcast, wowza

I am looking into building a live streaming site enabling users to sign in, create their own channel, and then live broadcast audio to listeners. However, I don't really know where to get started.

For example, how do I go about dynamically generating a permanent audio channel when a user signs up? What streaming software facilitates this process? I've looked into Wowza or Flash media server. Also Red5? But I understand it doesn't support streaming to mobile devices? Even Shoutcast or Icecast?

Just trying to get pointed in the right direction. Really appreciate the help and I apologize if this has been asked before, though I couldn't seem to find any similar questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only serving music from your servers, and to a specific web-based player, then HTTP will suffice.  You can have your users create playlists on your database, and simply serve up the playlists to the web-based client.

If instead you wish to create a regular stream that can be played by many clients, SHOUTcast/Icecast is all you need.  They are the server.  Next, you need a source.  There are a handful of tools for each platform for creating this source.  If you could describe better what you are shooting for, I might be able to provide a more specific recommendation.

Once you have these in place, you can easily build your service around them.  Mobile listeners aren't much different than desktop listeners... just lower bitrates generally.

Finally, I suggest not re-creating the wheel.  This has been done before many times over.  Look into [SHOUTcast Admin Pro](http://www.whmsonic.com/sap_features_root.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As for the source, what would be the best way to allow a user to record their own audio. Like either from their microphone, line-in input, etc?

Comment: SHOUTcast Source DSP, Ices, Edcast, SAM Broadcaster